# after toggling shouldAutorotate, orientation off

Tags: ios, autorotate

I have worked on this a for a while and googled everything related I can think of.

I have a button in my app that toggles rotation. When I turn rotation off, rotate the device, then turn rotation back on, I need a way to match the app orientation back to the device orientation.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    BOOL _rotationStatus;
}
```

Method tied to the button press:

```
   -(void)toggleRotation
    {
        if(_rotationStatus == NO)
        {        
            _rotationStatus = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            _rotationStatus = NO;
        }
    }


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate //only targeting iOS 6
{
    return !_rotationStatus;
}
```

This works great to toggle rotation, but when rotation is turned back on, orientation does not "refresh" to match device orientation until you rotate the device again.

For example

1. Device and app start in portrait.
2. Tap button to toggle rotation to off.
3. Rotate device to Landscape.
4. Device is landscape, app is portrait as expected.
5. Tap button to toggle rotation to on

Desired: App rotates to landscape to match device.

Actual: App remains in portrait until another rotation notification is received.

I think that a way to correct this would be to check the device orientation, and check the app orientation and match them up when rotation is toggled back to on.

I added this to the method:

```
if ((UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) && ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
        {
            NSLog(@"mis-matched Device and App orientations");
            //do the rotation?
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
        }
```

So the full method looks like this.

```
-(void)toggleRotation
{
        if(_rotationStatus == NO)
        {        
            _rotationStatus = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            _rotationStatus = NO;

            if ((UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) && ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait))
          {
              NSLog(@"mis-matched Device and App orientations");
              //do the rotation?
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
          }
        }
}
```

The NSLog prints when I expect it to, but the call to setStatusBarOrientation does not result in rotation.

I'm an iOS rookie, so I am sure I am doing many things wrong. Is there a better way to do this?